# Restore windows 7 using system image

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I made a system image only to the C drive, when I choose a recovery using system image from the repair your computer option on boot, will it format the entire hard disk or only the C drive ?

Answer (score 0):

It will format the partition with the operating system on, the repair console doesn't care about anything other than the operating system partition, so all other partitions (and other HDDs) should be safe.

Comment: If anything happens to the D drive, I will find you and I will format you :D

Thanks a lot man! :)

Comment: if you're really that concerned, open the computer and unplug the d: drive, that way no matter what happens, the data will be safe.